# Извлечение и вставка id при запросе к базе

Tags: php, mysql

Есть БД, где id AUTOINCREMENT. Как сделать запрос таким образом, что бы этот id, который был, автоинкрементом вытащился и вставился в другое поле в этой же таблице? По картинке более понятнее. Поле id и weight.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tab SET weight = id
WHERE weight= 0
```

Comment: жестко... вы предлагаете для изменения одного значения клонировать весь столбец? что там про минусы говорилось?

Comment: дополнил. задаем default для weight 0, апдейтим там, где не заполнено.
Альтернативно можно триггер навесить на "после вставки", работать с ним.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_insert_id()` возвращает 0, если предыдущий запрос не генерирует значение AUTO_INCREMENT. Если вам нужно сохранить значение на будущее, вызовите mysql_insert_id() сразу после запроса, генерирующего это значение.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table VALUE (NULL, 0, 0);
UPDATE table SET weight = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Answer (score -1):

Вы имеете в виду, чтоб при добавлении *новой* записи, сразу прописать ID этой записи в какое-то поле? Если да, то можно перед запросом INSERT узнать этот ID

```
$res_id = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table_name';");
$row_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_id);
$id = $row_id['Auto_increment'];
```

Comment: Это очень ненадежный способ, "id" нужно узнавать только после вставки.

Comment: "ненадежный способ"? Между этим запросом и запросом на INSERT пройдет около 0.0001 сек. А теперь прикиньте вероятность, с которой возможен случай, что кто-то в этот промежуток времени сделает другой INSERT

Comment: > пройдет около 0.0001 сек. А теперь прикиньте вероятность

Перефразируя известный скетч про архитекторов: "... пользователи, как правило, народ спокойный, думаю и погода не подведет."

Comment: Не люблю и не буду спорить, хотя была бы возможность, то провели бы с вами, как с "не спокойным пользователем" простой экперимент. Ну, да дело такое... Я показал принцип, но если уж на то пошло, то для "не спокойного" ничего не мешает сделать атомарную операцию:

    INSERT INTO `table_name` (`weight`) SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='db_name' and TABLE_NAME='table_name'

Если вы с этим знаком чуть больше, чем с работой архитекторов, то вопросов возникнуть не должно ))

Comment: Не уверен, что такая операция обеспечит параллелизм, сравнимый с возможностью генерации последовательностей предоставляемой сервером для клиентских сессий. Но гораздо лучше, чем предложение в ответе.

Comment: Ну, так с этого надо было и начинать ))) Фраза "*Не уверен, что такая операция обеспечит параллелизм*" всё расставила на свои места. Спасибо! С утра и так улыбнуло )) Закрываю своё участие в обсуждении.

Comment: Я наверное должен быть рад, но нет, не получается. Вы наверное себе не отдаете отчета, что приведенная операция состоит из двух атомарных, и если этот хак не устанавливает блокировку строки в TABLES, то одна из параллельных операций наестся с duplicate primary key... Но если это произойдет не более чем за 100 микросекунд - никто и не заметит :-D